# capture link using class as reference

Tags: node.js

I need your help in the following problem to automate a task, I have a class = "answer" is what differentiates it from other links, based on this class I need to get the link that changes for each client, part of the code follows

```
<tr data-id="b5d1a5c7-ad27-4a80-b9ea-80b20ba63f4d"  data-name="ANA PAULA" class="answer">
<td data-type="System.String" data-attribute="pmc_name_client" data-value="ANA PAULA" tabindex="0" data-th="Name Client" aria-label="Name Client ANA PAULA">
<a href="/oportunidades/detalhes-oportunidade/?id=b5d1a5c7-ad27-4a80-b9ea-80b20ba63f4d" class="details-link has-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show detail">ANA PAULA</a></td></tr>
```

Comment: Hi, you need to provide some code with what you got so far. We can't help you unless with more information. No one will write the code for you unless you have tried yourself.

Comment: <tr data-id="b5d1a5c7-ad27-4a80-b9ea-80b20ba63f4d"  data-name="ANA PAULA" class="answer">
<td data-type="System.String" data-attribute="pmc_name_client" data-value="ANA PAULA" tabindex="0" data-th="Name Client" aria-label="Name Client ANA PAULA">
<a href="/oportunidades/detalhes-oportunidade/?id=b5d1a5c7-ad27-4a80-b9ea-80b20ba63f4d" class="details-link has-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show detail">ANA PAULA</a></td></tr>